# binding to a static list and properties xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am making a portable Xamarin project. I have the following List in the class Stash:

```
public class Stash
{      
    public static List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

and a class Group:

```
public class Group
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

In another page in XAML I want to bind to a static list. I have a ListView that I want to bind to the Group List:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Stash.Groups}}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"
                Detail="{Binding GroupId}" DetailColor="Aqua">
            </TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I defined the Namespace in the local in XAML:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace"
```

My List is filled from the Sql Azure Database so it is not empty guys , Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code? I cant seem to display the list on my screen , All what is displayed is this sentence Namespace.Group .

Comment: What is the issue? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: i dont know , it does not display the group list for me ;( , did i wrote the code in the right way , have i missed something @Demitrian

Comment: how are you adding items to the list? at the moment it would be empty

Comment: it displays , Namespace.Data.Group , the namespacename  @Demitrian

Comment: no the items i have them on an Azure Account database for each user , so when i log in the user groups should show . @AppPack

Comment: Also, why don't you use an ObservableCollection? That implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which means that your UI will be properly updated when items are added to the collection.

Also, could you explain in more detail what you're seeing in UI? Is your ListView empty? It's quite difficult to help you when it's not clear exactly what the issue is.

Comment: i use a list because i dont want to change values , they will be fixed values , and my data is in sql on azure , In the UI i am seeing the namespace name instead of groups names . the code i wrote binding to a static list is the first time i write , is the binding correct ? am i missing som syntax ? @Demitrian

Comment: Alright. Could you add the full namespace of your `Stash` class to the first code block? It doesn't seem likely to me that it is `Namespace`.

Comment: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EluxFWA" @Demitrian

Comment: And your class called `Stash` Please remember that the `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<namespace>"`? definition has to contain the full namespace name to where the `List` can be found.

Comment: namespace EluxFWA
{
 public class Stash
 {

        public static List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();

Comment: this is the namespace i have , @Demitrian , is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, seems right. I would suggest that you update your question based on the questions you have been given. In doing so, then others who read your question can provide an answer without having to look through the comments.

Comment: ok thank you ::) @Demitrian

Comment: its working , i just removed IsGroupingEnabled="true" and it worked , this xamarin is crazy , now trying to make the list horizontally displaying , another challenge ;( @Demitrian

Answer (score 2):

The following binding is incorrect. You don't need to

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Stash.Groups}}"
```

You should change this to

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding {x:Static local:Stash.Groups}"
```

[Databinding Xamarin ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/)

Comment: its working , i just removed IsGroupingEnabled="true" and it worked , but thanks anyway , maybe you can help me with making this list horizontally displayed ? @Joshua Poling

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with the request. A listview does not allow for displaying data horizontally. There are other options depending on how much data you have, but take into account that if you have a couple of items they will run off the screen.

Answer (score 2):

its working , i just removed IsGroupingEnabled="true" and it worked

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Stash.Groups}}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"
            Detail="{Binding GroupId}" DetailColor="Aqua">
        </TextCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```